# Masking a string

Tags: javascript, string, masking

I need to put a received string in this format:

`"## ## ## ###"` in typescript/javascript

**Eg**:

`"12 34 56 789"`

I know there's `string-mask` and some way via JQuery, is there a simplier way to do it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could replace each pattern part with the wanted data.

```js
function format(value, pattern) {
    let i = 0;
    const v = value.toString();
    return pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => v[i++]);
}

console.log(format(123456789, '## ## ## ###'));
```

Comment: this is really awesome and so short, love it. Thanks for sharing, I now use it :)

Comment: @Nina Scholz What is the meaning of the underscore `(_)` character in the replace method?

Comment: it is a unused variable, which is shorter to write than `() => v[i++]`, which is a function without parameter. the underscore is a variable.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for your reply, but I got an unexpected result `23 45 67 89undefined` when the value is `023456789`.

Comment: @Yi-TingLiu, for leading zero/es, you need to hand over a string insted of a number, because numbers does not have a leading zeroes.

Comment: Does this works on key up ?

Comment: @CandleCoder, which keys?

Comment: Keyup event @NinaScholz

Comment: @CandleCoder, if you add it to the event? why not?

Answer (score 2):

I needed one that masks any character with a "*", from the beginning or end of the string, so I wrote the following:

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  /**
   * @param {string} str
   * @param {string} maskChar
   * @param {number} unmaskedLength
   * @param {boolean} [maskFromStart]
   * @returns {string}
   */
  mask(str, maskChar, unmaskedLength, maskFromStart = true) {
    const maskStart = maskFromStart ? 0 : Math.max(0, unmaskedLength);
    const maskEnd = maskFromStart ? Math.max(0, str.length - unmaskedLength) : str.length;
    return str
      .split("")
      .map((char, index) => {
        if (index >= maskStart && index < maskEnd) {
          return maskChar;
        }
        else {
          return char;
        }
      })
      .join("");
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The one which worked for me with the format `xxx-xxx-xxxx` with `keyup` **event**

```js
stringOnKeyUp.replace(/^(\d{3})$/g, '$1-').replace(/^(\d{3}-\d{3})$/g, '$1-');
```