# How to create pattern for numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a number `20220112` which i need to convert this number to string which will look like this

```
2022-01-12
```

Maybe anyone knows is there are some patterns in JS which I could use for easy conversion?

Something like

```
const date = patetn(****-**-**)
```

Comment: you could have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031441/masking-a-string/45031815#45031815).

Comment: `'20220112'.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3')`

Comment: Is that really a number? Or rather a string that contains only digits?

Comment: @Bergi It's a number

Comment: Then start with `.toString(10)`, check that it's really an 8-digit number, and do ordinary string operations on that. There's no builtin `pattern` function or something that would do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function where you first cast the passed value to a string. then you can format the string to your pattern.

```js
function formatNumber(num) {  
    return String(num).replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3');
}

console.log('formatted: ', formatNumber("20220401") )
```